# how do i read and output pwm with a black pill board?

Tags: arduino, project, stm32, arduino-ide

I am making an stm32 based motor speed controller for a DC motor. But I can't read PWM off my receiver and I can't make my MOSFET vary the output! I need help because now it's only on or off! I am using a RobotDyn BlackPill and an STP36NF06L Mosfet. And also I use Arduino ide with the STM board.
Code:

```
int Motor = PA15;
int rc = PB1;
int s;


void setup() {
  pinMode(Motor, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rc, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(Motor, LOW);
}
void loop() {
   if(s = (map(pulseIn(rc, HIGH), 1100, 1900, 0, 255)) > 200) {
    digitalWrite(Motor, HIGH);
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(Motor, LOW);
  }
  delay(10);
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar your components and wonder what are you expecting. You send HIGH or LOW, should that translate to ON and OFF which you wrote you are getting?

Comment: yes, I can only send HIGH or LOW signals to the MOSFET, I can`t send any PWM values.

Comment: digitalWrite sends high or low, nothing else, so perhaps you want to use analogWrite?

Comment: i cant when i put something like analogWrite(Motor, 100); doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read an external PWM signal you can use a timer in input capture mode, such that one channel triggers on the rising edge and the other triggers on the falling edge then compute the period and as such the frequency and duty cycle of the incoming signal. It is well documented in the reference manual and there are various examples and even YouTube tutorials of input capture mode.

Comment: how do i do that if my stm32 is flashed with arduino ide firmware, i cant use the stm32 app.

Comment: Registers, it's all in the reference manual